# Is there a way to create more options than 'choices' in Wagtail Form Builder

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, wagtail

I'm writing a new web page which should work also as enrollment platform to certain events. I would like to add `options['prices']` on the side of `options['choices']` in multiselect field.

Now there is a field for choices where choiceas are separated with comma, i want another to enter price difference from a default value depending on the choice (floats, though handling these can be done elsewhere) like `"1, 2.5, -1, 0"` . In the end of form it should count sum of default value and all possible selections.

I have tried to modify `wagtail.contrib.contrib.forms.FormBuilder.create_multiselect_field` without success. Is there a way to add this kind of functionality, basically just one additional options input?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way and again learned a lot.

Yes, this is possible, even rather easy way. My form is using AbstractEmailForm and i had to override following methods and variables:

Class MyForm(AbstractEmailForm):

```
form_builder = CustomFormBuilder

def get_submission_class(self):
    return CustomFormSubmission

def process_form_submission(self, form):
    #This function processed input data form.cleaned_data dict when user is submitting the form
    #Fields are defined in CustomFormSubmission

    total_price = self.default_price
    form_fields = self.get_form_fields()

    for i in form_fields:
        if i.prices: #if form creator has defined varying prices for choices
            #creates dict {key=choice, value=price} for every form field
            price_dict = dict(zip(
                [x.strip() for x in i.choices.split(',')],
                [Decimal(x.strip()) for x in i.prices.split(',')], #field type is DecimalField, float is not applicable
            ))

            total_price += price_dict[form.cleaned_data[i.label.lower()]]

    return self.get_submission_class().objects.create(
        form_data=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
        page=self,
        price=total_price,
    )

def get_data_fields(self):
    """
    Returns a list of tuples with (field_name, field_label).
    """

    data_fields = [
        ('submit_time', _('Submission date')),
        ('price', _('Total Price')),
    ]
    data_fields += [
        (field.clean_name, field.label)
        for field in self.get_form_fields()
    ]

    return data_fields
```

Also i had to create prices for choices as a field for form editor. This was possible by overriding AbstractFormField class. You have to override each create__field() function where you want prices option to apply. Ex. create_radio_field below:

class FormField(AbstractFormField):

```
prices = models.TextField(
    verbose_name=_('prices'),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_('Comma separated list of price changes.')
)

panels = [
    FieldPanel('label'),
    FieldPanel('help_text'),
    FieldPanel('required'),
    FieldPanel('field_type', classname="formbuilder-type"),
    FieldPanel('choices', classname="formbuilder-choices"),
    FieldPanel('prices'),
    FieldPanel('default_value', classname="formbuilder-default"),
]

def create_radio_field(self, field, options):
    options['choices'] = [(x.strip(), x.strip()) for x in field.choices.split(',')]
    options['prices'] = [x.strip() for x in field.prices.split(',')]
    return django.forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=django.forms.RadioSelect, 
        **options
    )
enter code here
#remember to create CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder) if you have custom fields, ex. Generic IP-address:

class CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder):
    def create_ipaddress_field(self, field, options):
        return forms.GenericIPAddressField(
            **options
    )
```

To save this value, define field to be created in database with CustomFormSubmission(AbstractFormSubmission)

```
price = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=16,
    decimal_places=2,
    default=0,
)

def get_data(self):
    """
    Returns dict with form data.
    """
    form_data = json.loads(self.form_data)
    form_data.update({
        'submit_time': self.submit_time,
        'price': self.price,
    })

    return form_data
```

Currency is saved in django models.DecimalField as it requires only 2 decimals. Floats might have strange behaviour at rounding.

If you have any questions I'd be happy to open this code for more!